# X-Rite Video Color Matching gives Strange Results

Tags: davinci-resolve, color-correction, color-grading

I’m attempting to grade some footage from a C100, with the aid of X-Rite’s Video color match card, in DaVinci Resolve. Below is a screen grab of the ungraded footage.

[image]

And here is what I get when matching to the card:

[image]

It’s a good start, as far as I’m concerned...except for red...why on earth would those red candles turn magenta? Is there something that I can do to overcome that?

Comment: Those color charts are very sensitive, and your color management settings are very important. Without more details, no one will be able to help you, and even seasoned colorists have trouble getting consistent results with those charts. Patrick inhoffer on mixinglight.com has revisited the subject multiple times over the years and often walks away with a less solid explanation. If you manage to find a decent starting point for grading and can do it consistently, you’re doing well. Shifts in saturated colors might be from output c.s. clipping, or could be simply incorrect transforms.

Comment: My guess is those candles were close to "out of gamut" in original, and after color adjustment they are "really out of gamut now". You can check with the color scope.